# Firebase Authentication code expired error

Tags: android, firebase




I had created phone auth for my android app using flutter-firebase. When the Android Device verification from cloud console is off, it redirects to a captcha screen and automatically captcha gets verified and after entering the otp received, app login functionality works properly.

But when Android Device verification is on ,for not showing the captcha screen,it shows this error on entering the otp :

Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null. I/flutter (27447): [firebase_auth/session-expired] The sms code has expired. Please re-send the verification code to try again.
My Flutter,Firebase Auth version is updated, and sha1 and sha256 are already added in firebase project setting.

Cant find a solution ,please guide.

Comment: You need to submit a minimal reproducible code so we can understand how you are doing it and help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass an empty function to **verificationCompleted** as param in the **verifyPhoneNumber** function.

```
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

      await auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
          phoneNumber: this.widget.phoneNumber,
          timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5),
          verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential){},
          verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
          codeSent: codeSent,
          codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: codeAutoRetrievalTimeout,
          forceResendingToken: _forceResendToken)
```